# Optimizing MySQL query, cannot change the DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

I am in a bit of a trouble, i have a query that works fine for me, however it kills the production servers (generating an error)

```
SELECT
      p.people_id,
      p.firstname,
      p.lastname,
      p.matchname,
      p.type,
      p.date_of_birth,
      a.name as nationality
    FROM
       (
        SELECT p.lastname, p.nationality, p.type, p.date_of_birth, 
                COUNT(p.people_id) num_people
        FROM people p
        WHERE p.date_of_birth IS NOT NULL
          AND p.people_id NOT IN 
            (
                SELECT people_id 
                FROM people_not_duplicated 
            UNION 
                SELECT connected_player_id AS people_id 
                FROM people_not_duplicated
            )
        GROUP BY p.lastname, p.date_of_birth, p.type,p.gender
        HAVING num_people > 1
        ) pj
    INNER JOIN people p ON pj.lastname = p.lastname 
          AND pj.date_of_birth = p.date_of_birth
    LEFT JOIN area a ON p.nationality = a.area_id

-- this query has been KILLED!!
```

I'm not particularly good at optimizing SQL queries since writing this one was super hard for me. Does anyone have any tips on how to speed up this query? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Cron script for generating ErrorViews results couldn't start as lock exists.

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve]. Read questions asking about query optimization to get an idea of what else is relevant. Read the MySQL documentation sections on indexes & query optimization. Eg show DDL & query plans. The NOT IN UNION can be NOT IN AND NOT IN. There is no point in selecting from people then joining with people. Also, if you *have* people_not_duplicated then why use count > 1? And what does "cannot change DB" mean *exactly*? Suspect lack of indexes.

Comment: It means that i cannot alter the DataBase. Thanks for the link i will look into the ASAP.

Comment: people_not_duplicated is a table where I keep people with same data (eg twins) so that I know that i know that duplicated people from this table is not an error. the query itself is finding duplicated people which are not listed in people_not_duplicated and are mentioned in the DB more than once. I dont know if I explained it good enough. I read the documentation before asking the question here, its just i myself am a beginner and cant see a usage for the documentation solutions.

Comment: What is more - the query worked fine until recently, i guess the extend of the db finally killed the performance of the query.

Comment: Come back after transforming `IN ( SELECT ... )` into `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ... AND ... IS NULL`.

Comment: thanks @RickJames havent thought about that, the proposed solution solved the problem!